# Does a conscientious objector have the same rights as someone with religious exemption?

Tags: united-states, employment, business, privacy, religion

There are several laws that [allow the omission](http://www.twc.state.tx.us/news/efte/employees_without_ssns.html) of an SSN to employers and non-governmental agencies. The general context of those laws is a religious basis.

As America becomes more secular, I wonder if there will be a "test of faith" to be eligible to exemption under certain laws.

Can an Atheist or Agnostic claim the equivalent religious exception, but under conscious objector grounds? (or similar)